# Multivariate Time series forecasting on ARIMA

Tags: arima

I am trying to do some Multivartive time series forecasting with closing stock price and sentiment score. I used an ARIMA but I am not getting the result I required.

[I got this when the lines should have fitted the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giJ7V.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.